# ¿Como guardar la descripción de un usuario para mostrarla en una listview?

Tags: java, android-studio, base-de-datos, sqlite, listview

¿Qué tal? Estoy tratando de hacer una app donde ocupo SQLite para hacer el registro pero después quiero que cuando ya estén en su sesión puedan hacer más cambios para cada usuario, individualmente como poner una descripción, también que puedan adjuntar archivos (aunque esa es otra pregunta si pueden contestarla sería grandioso) y después de todo eso mostrarla en una ListView para que la puedan visualizar alguien más...

[image: Base_de_Datos]

La pregunta es ¿Lo agrego a mi Base de datos SQLite? y después la muestro o hay alguna otra forma ya que la base de datos ya la tengo creada y si pongo más información ¿lo hago desde la que ya tengo o creo otra? ¿Afecta en algo a mi logging?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! De tu pregunta no se entiende mucho tu problema.. que no sabes usar de la base de datos? si ya almacenas informacion, cual es el problema para almacenar mas?

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias tratare de ser más específica

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: Y te recomandaria urgentemente que leas lo que es una base de datos y lo que hace...